# Is there a multiple pairwise sign test?

Tags: r, machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have data that are not normally distributed (the paired differences).

I want a pairwise statistical test to find the differences between the three groups only (because I have 11 groups).

Pairwise Wilcoxon test was one of the options. However, I found a [**PAPER**](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0003347209005247?token=301148165821CF50F7C1A9033E9B0756C8C5499948D914B93CE15B93FEC097F4EA33483FA49605B30688FDB734A5174A) stated that the paired difference must be symmetry to run this test, while my data is not.

So the second option is to use the Friedman test and then post-hoc Friedman nemenyi test, which can be used safely for all my groups not for three specific pairs.

I need a test like **sign test** which does not assume normality and symmetry for comparing only three pairs. Something like `pairwise.wilcox.test.` / `pairwise.t.test` function in R software .

I google pairwise **sign test** in R, but I found nothing in the literature—only the `SignTest` function in R for two paired samples.

Can I find a way to perform pairwise sign test in R?

Comment: Do you mean doing some kind of ANOVA on 12 groups and then doing two-group comparisons with three groups? If so, you’re not doing paired testing.

Comment: @Dave, I mean to select 3 specific groups and then to perform pairwise comparisons for them.

Comment: Paired testing means one-sample testing of pairwise differences, such as before and after measurements. A big hint (but not requirement) that you’re not doing paired testing is if the sample sizes are different in your two groups.

Comment: @Dave, the sample size is the same for groups. Suppose I have A, B, C. I want to see the differences between A, B and A, C and B, C. This is the idea of my question.

Comment: Do you have natural pairings between subjects in the groups, and do you find the differences between paired observations and then run a one-sample test on the differences?

Comment: @Dave, yes I have paired samples. yes, this can be done using, for example, pairwise.wilcox.test. function in R, but as I said the differences is not symmetry and I cannot use this test. This is the reason why I am looking for the pairwise sign test.

Comment: “Differences is not symmetry” I do not follow what you mean by this, and it seems to be a critical component of what you want to do. Please edit your question to explain this.

Comment: @Dave one of the Wilcoxon test assumptions is that the differences between paired observations should be symmetry. I will add the paper to the question.

Comment: Are you missing a word in your first line? "*even though the paired differences*" ...